# Optimisation of WPF QR Decoding App which uses ~100% CPU usage on Intel NUC NUC7CJYH

Tags: c#, wpf, aforge, zxing.net

I have been working on a WPF which decodes a QR Code that the user holds up to a webcam. The app works rather well, and runs on my dev machine fine (max 23% CPU and 4% GPU usage on a Core i7 3770 CPU, NVidia Quadro K4200 GPU) but when I install and run it on the machine it will be used on (an Intel NUC NUC7CJYH) CPU usage is > 94% for the app, leading to 100% usage on the machine.

Currently, the app scans the user's QR code twice - the first is the employee's QR code, and the second is a QR code for the Project Number that they've worked on. The app uses ZXing.Net to decode QR codes, and AForge.Net to access the webcam.

I have run the VS Profiler and this is a screenshot of the results:
[VS Profiler Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk8e1.jpg)

According to the VS Profiler results, there are 4 method calls that are using the most amount of CPU time and presumably I should be focusing on:

- videoSource_NewFrame: This obtains each frame rendered in the VideoCaptureDevice (part of the AForge.Video.DirectShow class) and displays it in an Image control called imgSource. This is using ~10.56% of total CPU time (3745ms)

  ```
  void videoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
  {
      try
      {
          BitmapImage bi;
          using (var bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone())
          {
              bi = new BitmapImage();
              bi.BeginInit();
              MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
              bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
              ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
              bi.StreamSource = ms;
              bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
              bi.EndInit();
          }
          bi.Freeze();
          Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate { imgSource.Source = bi; }));
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          MessageBox.Show("Error with attaching video frame.\n " + ex.Message);
          MessageBox.Show("An error occurred. \nPlease contact the Systems Development team for assistance.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
          return;
      }

  }
  ```
- timer_Tick: This method is a DispatcherTimer Tick EventHandler and is called at an interval of 1 second. This is used to display the current Time in the lblTime control, and it's using ~9.56% of CPU time (3389ms)

  ```
  private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      currentTime = new DateTime();
      ts = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);
      currentTime = currentTime.Date + ts;

      lblTime.Content = $"{currentTime.ToString("HH:mm")}"; 
  }
  ```
- qrTimer_Tick: Another DispatcherTimer Tick EventHandler. This method is called every 3 seconds and initiates scanning for a QR code at each interval. It's using ~5.52% (1959ms)

  ```
  try
  {
      MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
      var encoder = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BmpBitmapEncoder();
      encoder.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(imgSource.Source as System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource));
      encoder.Save(memoryStream);
      memoryStream.Flush();

      capturedImage = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream);

      BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();

      reader.AutoRotate = true;
      reader.TryInverted = true;
      reader.Options = new DecodingOptions { TryHarder = true };

      if (capturedImage != null)
          result = reader.Decode(capturedImage);

      if (result != null)
      {
          if (isStep1 == true)
          {
              QRScanUserID();                        
          }
          else if (isStep1 == false & isStep2 == true)
          {
              QRScanProjectID();                        
          }
      }                

  }
  catch (Exception)
  {                
      MessageBox.Show("An error occurred. \nPlease contact the Systems Development team for assistance.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
      return;
  }
  ```
- An external call to the Decode method of ZXing.Net. This uses 5.34% of total CPU time (1895ms)

I am not sure how I could optimise the code. I have looked at setting the DispactherPriority for each of the two DispatcherTimers, but in testing this has no effect on the app's CPU usage and interferes with each DispatcherTimer's intervals. I have also tried changing the 3 BarcodeReader options that I have configured in the qrTimer_Tick method to false, which yielded an improvement of about 1%. However, I would assume this is negligible as it depends on factors such as how quickly the user places the QR code in front of the camera and if the qrTimer_Tick has already fired.

Is there something I am missing? Could it just be that the app is overpowering the NUC machine it's running on?

**EDIT**
After following recommendations from kennyzx and lerthe61, I have managed to get the app's CPU usage on the NUC NUC7CJYH down to ~58% at peak. The largest benefit was in removing the DispatcherTimer object which was calling the timer_Tick Event Handler every second. Running VS Profiler shortly after I made this change showed a peak CPU usage of 18% on my dev machine, which was shortly after startup with the app having to get itself going.

After lerthe61's input, I then had a look at my use of MemoryStream and Bitmap objects. The videoSource_NewFrame method now looks as follows:

```
void videoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            try
            {
                BitmapImage bi;

                capturedImage = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.BeginInit();
                ms = new MemoryStream();
                capturedImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                bi.StreamSource = ms;
                bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bi.EndInit();
                bi.Freeze();
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate { imgSource.Source = bi; }));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error with attaching video frame.\n " + ex.Message);
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred. \nPlease contact the Systems Development team for assistance.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return;
            }

        }
```

I have now used lock in the qrTimer_Tick method to lock out the current captured Image coming from the webcam:

```
if (capturedImage != null)
{
   lock (_qrTimerLock)
   {
      result = reader.Decode(capturedImage);
   }
}
```

Despite my using a lock, the app occasionally throws the error "Object is currently in use elsewhere." My refactoring of the code has had little effect on the app's CPU usage efficiency above removing timer_Tick, so I could leave it as it was, however that is obviously less efficient.

Comment: @dumetrulo thanks for the edit. Posting code always shows me flames and I don't know why :/

Comment: is it a coincidence the CPU on your dev machine has 4 cores while NUC7CJYH is a single core CPU? Please check if both my assumptions are true.

Comment: @kennyzx I believe it's a dual core (see [link](https://ark.intel.com/products/128992/Intel-Celeron-J4005-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-2_70-GHz)) . However, it is a Celeron (J4005) and it has onboard graphics, so you may be onto something here... There isn't any noticeable performance degradation, however I don't like the fact that it's maxed out since this is the machine the app will be running on

Comment: Looks like 100% of NUC7CJYH CPU power is used by 2 threads (it can handle 2 concurrent threads). The i7 3770 4 cores CPU can handle 8 threads. That is why you get a usage of roughly 25%. Can you make the tick interval of the timers longer?

Comment: You can check the number of threads and number of cores from the link you provided. And in your code, one thread is used for the videosource, the other thread is for the dispatcher timers. Both of them are running at 100%. Could you add some time stamps to assess how much time does it take to handle qr_TimerTick?

Comment: 1. You are starting a new thread on each frame just to update image;
2. What the purpose to Clone each bitmap from Camera?
3. It is not clear why the code in DispatcherTimer is so complicated. What the difference with; ``lblTime.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm")`` ?
4. The is a conversion from MemoryStream into Bitmap (probably, to show on form) and again from that bitmap into MemoryStream and again into Bitmap:
Listing1: ``bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp)``
Listing3: ``encoder.Save(memoryStream)``
Listing3: ``capturedImage = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream)``

Comment: @kennyzx I'd have never thought that that would have been an issue. I was under the impression that DispatcherTimer objects ran within the UI thread and wouldn't be needing threads of their own. I'm still new to it as well. Regarding the intervals, I can remove the timer object with the tick interval of 1 second since the app doesn't actually need it. I've noticed qr_TimerTick starting ~3.239s into the app's execution and ending ~3.451s, so it takes roughly 300ms

Comment: @lerthe61 to try and answer your points (I am new to Aforge.Net and using the camera in a WPF app, please bear with me): 1. I assume you're referring to this line: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate { imgSource.Source = bi; })); By my understanding, this is to show the most recent frame from the Camera in the imgSource control. 2. By my understanding this copies the current frame shown by the camera so it can be converted into a bitmap and displayed on the form 3. Can't remember why I took such a complicated route, but the interval that timer_Tick runs at makes it overkill

Comment: @lerthe61 4. I am having a look at the code now and will see how I can rework this

Answer (score 0):

I decided to settle on removing the DispatcherTimer that was running every second, leaving the second DispatcherTimer object which runs every 3 seconds. The app's performance is favourable using just this fix.

Thanks to everyone for the help!